# xcode 5 : can i still create application for ios 5?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios5, ios7, xcode5

Is it possible to create an application that could be executed on `iOS 5` devices with the new `Xcode 5`? On the software update page, within the app store, there is an `Xcode 5` update available, but i am wondering if it would be a wise thing to do to update to Xcode 5.

My major concern is whether i could still create applications targeting iOS 5, and if i could still work on old projects targeting `iOS 5`.

I have searched through SO but seems there is not much related resources yet. Please shed some light on this. Thanks!

Comment: it seems that upgrading to Xcode 5 is a relatively safe thing to to, after all. i will be upgrading it soon and will post again here if there are problems in Xcode 5 with legacy apps designed for iOS 5. thanks everyone for the answers and comments!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

in xcode5 **Preference** you can download the `simulator` for iOS 5.0, iOS 5.1, iOS 6.0, iOS 6.1 like below image from Xcode Download preference:

[image]

After set Deployment Target:-

[image]

here you getting option for testing which simulatore:-

[image]

Comment: Quick question, if I update the App using 7.0 SDK as Deployment target, would the users who are still on iOS 6 be able to download the update via App Store or just users who are on iOS7?

Comment: if deployment target is 6 then they user can update the app who are creating in ios7 sdk

Comment: So if deployment target is iOS7, users who bought the App who are on iOS 6 would not be able to download it (that's what I want, btw)? Thanks.

Comment: Worth to add: if development target is lower than user's iOS, users will not know, that there is an update.

Comment: yes @TomaszBąk is right if yo are set deplyment targe 7.0 then this app not showing on that users who are not using ios7

Comment: @TomaszBąk and Nithin Thanks guys. Just one more thing: I added UIDynamics in the update, deployment target is iOS6, tested on both iOS 6 and iOS 7 simulators, no crash even on iOS 6 simulator (even calling UIDynamics methods on iOS 6 simulator). So I wonder if this would hold true on a real iOS 6 device, which I don't have at the moment.

Comment: might be that is not an issue if simulator runs well then device as well as support.

Comment: Is it possible to develop for iOS5 using XCode 6?

Answer (score 6):

One thing of note:

The iOS 5 simulator is only available for download if you're running Xcode 5 under Mountain Lion. If you're running Mavericks then you can't download or use it.

Comment: You can run Mountain Lion in a virtual environment, such as Parallels Desktop. Or you could install Mountain Lion on an external hard drive. Or you find an iOS 5 device (like iPad 1) and use that for testing. I know it sucks, but those are our only options as of 2014.

Comment: I've compiled a handy list of other things to watch out for here: http://pinkstone.co.uk/how-to-build-apps-for-ios-5-with-xcode-5/

Comment: No, you can't even use an iOS 5 device because XCode 5 will not let you provisioning it and therefore can't be accepted to install your app

Comment: @broch I'm using an iPad 1 with Xcode 5 and it's working fine - I could set it as a development device just like any other iOS device. Does this not work at your end?

Comment: @Jay Versluis No unfortunately. I have an iPod 3rd gen with iOS 5.1 and XCode will not even recognize it. Usually it goes more or less automatic with the provisioning but I couldn't get it to work.

Comment: @Jay Versluis Well, I should have clicked your link before. By changing the iOS target to 5.1.1 it suddenly works. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

Yes , you can create and test your application on iOS 5.0 simulator too in Xcode 5.

They would just be created with the iOS 7.0 SDK as the base SDK

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can still do App compatible with iOS5

Just set the [image: Deployment Target to 5.0] in your projets settings (General tab)

But you have to be aware that by default, XCode will use the last SDK (7.0), this means that your app will have the new iOS7 native design on iOS7 devices

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible, in the project configuration you have to select the correct **Deployment Target** (in your case 5.0).
The only problem is that you are creating an app with the new SDK 7.0, so your application will use the new user experience.